# PostgreSQL larger with NULL values

Tags: sql, postgresql, null

I am trying to explore various of ways efficiently store zeros in my PostgreSQL table. The table rows looks like this:

```
id        kwh     created_time                device_id
269536    5080    "2015-06-19 09:42:01+02"    "00:12:4B:00:01:1F:BE:BC"
269537    0       "2015-06-19 08:42:00+02"    "00:12:4B:00:01:1F:BE:BC"
```

The column `kwh` consists of `integer` values. Since 54% of these are zero-values I converted all zero-values to `NULL` values.

```
id        kwh     created_time                device_id
269536    5080    "2015-06-19 09:42:01+02"    "00:12:4B:00:01:1F:BE:BC"
269537    NULL    "2015-06-19 08:42:00+02"    "00:12:4B:00:01:1F:BE:BC"
```

Afterwards, **I expected to see a decrease in overall size of the table since NULL Values only consume 1 bit.** But no. The table space has went from 608kb to 936kb (after `FULL VACUUM`).

Why am I experiencing this increase?

Comment: Only `VACUUM FULL` can compact the tuples.

Comment: I also performed a full vacuum. I'll edit the question right away.

Comment: This is maybe of theoretical interest, but it is the kind of "optimisation" for which the net effect on system performance and database size is going to be almost impossible to accurately measure, and I can't imagine a case where I'd want to implement such a methodology. You'd certainly save more space by using an integer as your device_id.

Comment: premature optimization.

Comment: When you say "the table space went"... Show exactly how you determined that please. Also, are you sure it was `VACUUM FULL`? Are you perhaps on a fairly old PostgreSQL version? Show `SELECT version()` output. Unless you changed the `FILLFACTOR` there's *no way* that should've increased the size after `VACUUM FULL`.